# What is in the Merovingian’s cake?

Tags: the-matrix

I've re-watched the *Matrix* films recently and I'm confused about the scene in the restaurant with the Merovingian.

He's talking with Neo when the film cuts to a woman eating a cake. I've found the bit from the script. (source: [wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Reloaded))

> I have sent her dessert, a very special dessert. I wrote it myself. It starts so simply, each line of the program creating a new effect, just like poetry. First, a rush... heat... her heart flutters. You can see it, Neo, yes? She does not understand why - is it the wine? No. What is it then, what is the reason? And soon it does not matter, soon the why and the reason are gone, and all that matters is the feeling itself. This is the nature of the universe. We struggle against it, we fight to deny it, but it is of course pretense, it is a lie. Beneath our poised appearance, the truth is we are completely out of control. Causality. There is no escape from it, we are forever slaves to it.

He wrote the cake himself? Is it a virus like Agent Smith? I'm really confused. Is he trying to 'hack' the woman with the cake?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I'm not sure there's anything to add in an answer that you didn't write in the question. He wrote a program (a trojan malware, not a virus, to be more technically precise, since it didn't replicate) to have effect on that woman. Same way Architect wrote code to give someone a feeling they are tasting beef or chicken or oatmel

Comment: An interesting pre-portal reference to "the cake is a lie"

Comment: Perhaps [Sally](http://youtu.be/F-bsf2x-aeE) had some of the same cake.

Comment: [`c:\funky_cold_medina.bat`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OP5EnaaYjQ)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truffle_oil

Comment: http://31.media.tumblr.com/47cea8d99373a9e085f78389086996f4/tumblr_n2ta5gjkjE1sixr64o1_400.gif

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I wish there was a way to upvote that comment a thousand times.

Comment: Milk, eggs, flour, sugar, oil, salt, baking powder, vanilla, and just a *dash* of love.

Comment: @Monty129: aw, thank you. If there’s one thing that could have saved the Matrix sequels, it’s a late-80s novelty rap number thrown in somewhere.

Comment: Lol, you can't replicate it dude, you'll just have to rely in the old fashioned way to make a woman react that way.

Answer (score 18):

Hacking the Matrix is an established ability of nearly all parties involved. Agents, or their supervisors, can alter bluepills (those still hard-wired into the Matrix) and places or items, such as when the hotel windows change from accessible to bricked-over.

In the real world, Operators can hack the Matrix by placing people wherever they like (within reason apparently; Link refers to Trinity's entry in the last half of Reloaded as a messy hack) and providing them with weapons - the Operator can even 'hack' the individuals, giving them knowledge on-the-fly; the helicopter scene being a great example of this.

Neo is of course able to 'remake the Matrix' as he deems fit, though he tends to limit this to a few simple abilities like flight, telekinetics, a little bit of precognition and a very very high health meter.

With that being a recurring theme in the Matrix movies -- the cake contains a program which causes the one that consumes it to orgasm. That's it. vOv

Comment: I have to say that "Zionist ship" sounds quite bad. Even if true, and has nothing to do with politics and current events.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I thought MxO referred to humans that were dedicated to fighting the Machines 'Zionists'. I'll change it, I don't want to cross the streams

Comment: That's from another movie.

Comment: Thanks Stick. @Mr Lister: I think that "to cross the streams" has entered the idioms list of the English language.

Comment: Wait? You censored "Zion" in reference to The Matrix? The ships as operated in "the real world", during the course of the movies are under military command of "Zion". Calling them "Zionist ships" is probably the most accurate way of describing them. Especially since there are theories that "the dessert of the real" is in fact just another layer of the Matrix.

Comment: *"..the cake contains a program which causes the one that consumes it to orgasm."* ..and to blow the Merovingian in the ladies toilets, moments later.  Yes he was definitely 'hacking' her if you take 'hacking' to mean changing her behavior to suit his will.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - hunh, I'd never considered that the woman he met up with might have been her. Is there a way to verify that? Maybe it's been too long since I've watched the sequels to the Matr -- then again, maybe not

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - yeah, well, 'Zionist' having a meaning outside the movies, and it never really being applied *within* the movies, I guess I didn't feel like it was as applicable a term anymore. Meh. NBD

Comment: @Stick  I believe (from memory) she walks to a prominent point of the restaurant and looks at him, just before he makes his hasty departure.  It was Persephone's look as this was occurring, that later 'clinched it' (when she told the henchman where to find him) for me.

Comment: @Stick considering how much of the matrix resembles Judeo-Christian themes, the term is very apt.

Comment: the cake was a lie.

Answer (score 14):

The Merovingian wrote the cake program himself, but it was to give the woman an orgasm so that he could more easily persuade her to return the favor (and also to make his point about choice). Evidently she did return the favor since Persephone later references the lipstick on the Merovingian and comments that

> She wasn't kissing your face, my love.

Answer (score 7):

The word everybody is looking for is **Aphrodisiac**. The Merovingian gave her a powerful aphrodisiac.

> **aph·ro·dis·i·ac**
>   (n) a food, drink, or drug that stimulates sexual desire.
>   *"the Romans worshiped the apple as an aphrodisiac"*
>         synonyms:  love potion
>
> (ad) a thing that causes excitement.
>   *"for a few seconds she'd fallen for the powerful aphrodisiac of music"*

Comment: This answer is off-topic and should be migrated to http://english.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Amyl nitrate and MDMA, +1